# Autocomplete does NOT work second time on Bootstrap Modal Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a bootstrap modal dialog where I have an input for autocomplete.

When I open the dialog I launch the function:

```
<code>
$(document).on('keyup', 'input[name=item]', function() {
    var products = new Array();
    /* Get All Products */
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=order/order/getproducts',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                products[i] = json[i];
            }
        }
    });
    /* Autocomplete By Got Products */
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: products
    });
    $(this).autocomplete('option', 'appendTo', '.item');
});
</code>
```

And autocomplete works well.

But when I close the dialog by `$(myModal).modal('hide');` and launch it second time the autocomplete does not work.

Why, could you please explain?

Comment: "Not Working the second time" problems are most often the case of failing to unbind the connection to the button on close.   As you are just 'hiding' it, you don't actually unbind it.   So, try `$(myModal).modal('hide').off();`

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on jsfiddle?

Comment: If I add '.off()' hiding stops working.

Comment: No, I cant reproduce this on jsfiddle cos I cant create a modal there.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier, I used same approach so I also faced same issue, to resolve that I made following changes:

Introduced onkeypress event:

```
<input id="superAdminEmail" onkeypress="onTextInsert()" name="Email" class="form-control" required>
```

Update javascript code:

```
function onTextInsert() {
$("#superAdminEmail").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        showLoaderScreen();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/admin/getadminemailsuggestion',
            data: { 'prefixemail': $("#superAdminEmail").val() },
            success: function (result) {
                response($.map(result, function (item) {
                    var res = { label: item.Email, value: item.Name };
                    hideLoaderScreen();
                    return res;
                }));
            },
            error: function (error) {
                hideLoaderScreen();
            }
        });
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#superAdminEmail").val(ui.item.label);
        $("#superAdminName").val(ui.item.value);
        return false;
    }
});

$("#superAdminEmail").autocomplete("option", "appendTo", "#superAdminModal");
```

}